# How to get value of nested items using known value in realtime firebase

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the name by using mobile no the database looks like this in realtime firebase

```
customers
    -NU0YxXr37qEM8gT73KB
       firstName:"asa"
       lastName:"asaa"
       mobile:"1234567890"
       place:"aaaa"
```

I tried the following code

```
     const customersRef = ref(db, 'customers');
     const equalToQuery = query(customersRef,orderByChild("mobile"),equalTo('1234567890'));
```

and

```
const equalToQuery = query(customersRef, equalTo('mobile', "1234567890"));
get(equalToQuery)
    .then((snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot.val())
      
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

I also changed the rule and index on mobile like this

```
"customers": { 
".indexOn": ["mobile"] // or "mobile"
    }
```

I am getting null value at snapshot.val()

Comment: The code and index look fine to me at first, so likely there is something else going on that we can't see. Can you set up a minimal repro on a site like jsbin/jsfiddle/stackblitz?